# Helping with understanding comics dialogue

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Can you help me understand their last dialogue?

there is no prior information other than that

man in yellow - Jason Blood

Indian - Randu, Indian delegate to the UN

third guy - Harry Matthews - advertising manager, their friend

in particular, I do not understand the meaning of phrases (not words, namely phrases):

- He needs all he can get in the advertising bussines
- In my firm you need a vacation  every five minutes
  [image]

Comment: Harry needs all *the nerves* he can get - as though he needs to replace them, because the advertising business is stressful - hard on the nerves. The need for a vacation every 5 minutes is also a reference to the stressfulness of the job.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text.  Type out what you're interested in.

Comment: @stangdon isn't photo here helpful to understand the context of the dialogue?

Comment: @Ishayahu  Then type the context.  But pictures cannot be searched like text and are unfriendly to users with vision problems or using assistive technologies.